# Create Ranking From Database With PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask, how to create a rank from a table of scores that I had from database? For example, the table of database has student_id, course_id, scores. I have create a php code to get these scores and accummulate it as Final Score. Then, I need to create who get the first rank, second, and more. Here's my sample code:

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbstudent");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
   $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbscores WHERE student_id = '".$r['student_id']."'");
   $total = 0;
   while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2))
   {
      $total += $r2['scores'];
   }
   echo "<tr><td>$total</td><td>/* for rank*/</td></tr>";
}
```

So, I have get the total scores, but how to get the rank for these student? For example my result right now is (name, scores, rank):

```
  1. Ryan - 235
 2. Jack - 450
 3. Dave - 140
 4. Levi - 330
 5. Kens - 350
```

And what I want to is like these:

```
  1. Dave - 235 - 4
 2. Jack - 450 - 1
 3. Levi - 140 - 5
 4. Kens - 330 - 3
 5. Ryan - 350 - 2
```

Don't give me answer to get it from database using AVERAGE, SUM, etc, because I have another calculation for the scores. So anyone know how to create it with PHP?

Comment: Please don't tell us what can and cannot provide by way of an answer. Also I don't understand how rank relates to scores, but I suppose we should expect such a state of affairs

Comment: And [do not use mysql_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/870729).  Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @strawberry rank related to scores, the highest the scores, the lowest the rank. As You could see from my example, Dave got rank 4 because his score 235, and Jack get first rank because he got the highest score.

Comment: @cale_b As I write above, it's my sample code, don't tell me about PDO etc, because I already use that at my real program. I just want to simplify the code so anyone can (or i hope) understand my code

Comment: this can be done in PHP only, or entirely in mysql. The choice is yours

Comment: Ryan's score is higher than kens' but he got a higher rank

Comment: I **will** tell you, and **everyone else who sees this question** that using mysql is dangerous and not suggested.  You are very bossy for someone who is asking for help.

Comment: By which cale_b means PHP's MySQL api. Anyway, the code is a mess. But that's another story.

Comment: @Drew How to do that?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, Typos.

Comment: @cale_b sorry to hurt You, but as I wrote above, I just want to simplify but many people like You just comment about PDO, mysqli, bad code, not a good code.. But they're only comment it, not answering it.

Comment: if I write it, then I have to explain it, and you have to maintain it, and it takes an hour. Seems there are enough examples out there for mysql-only querying for ranking. So I would suggest go with your comfort zone. If that is PHP-only below, I would steer that way. But any serious effort at research and this question isn't even here :P

Comment: @Drew it's Okay, just give me a logic (using array or what), and I will try to create it.. Thanks before

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/zzfatbx  -- a google on the keywords stackoverflow mysql ranking variables

Comment: @Drew that's the problem.. I googled a wrong keyword... Thank You very much Drew! Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates an array which stores the totals, then sorts them and displays them in a list.

The array is indexed by student id.

```
$rankingArray = [];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbstudent");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
   $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbscores WHERE student_id = '".$r['student_id']."'");
   $total = 0;
   while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2))
   {
      $total += $r2['scores'];
   }
   $rankingArray[$r['student_id']] = $total;
   echo "<tr><td>$total</td><td>/* for rank*/</td></tr>";
}

asort($rankingArray);
$rankNumber = 1;
foreach ($rankingArray as $id => $rank) {
    echo $rankNumber.' '.$id.' '.$rank.PHP_EOL;
    $rankNumber++;
}
```

It would be better to use MySQL to handle this and have PHP just display the results.

Comment: No it wouldn't . Why do you say it would?

Comment: Because MySQL has this functionality built in.   Coding it in PHP is spending time working on something that doesn't need to be done.

Comment: No conversation around a question like this should neglect to mention that it's [not good to use mysql_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/870729)

Comment: MySQL has built in ranking capabilities? Are you sure? Even if if did, I'm not convinced that that would clinch the debate

Comment: actually, this code is not working, but I use Your logic to my code, and it works fine. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use MySQL ORDER BY function

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbstudent tst LEFT JOIN tbscores tsc ON tst.id = tsc.student_id ORDER BY tsc.score DESC");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
 $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbscores WHERE student_id = '".$r['student_id']."'");
 $total = 0;
 while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2))
 {
  $total += $r2['scores'];
}
echo "<tr><td>$total</td><td>/* for rank*/</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: And it's even better to [Not use mysql_ at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/870729)

Comment: As I said above, I have a calculation in my PHP code for the end result, so I can't use MySQL queries